# How to get the authentificated user information in Model Serializer in Django Rest?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a **LinkList** object, which has owner property - the username of the User it belongs to. I am trying to have LinkLists be linked to the user that made the create request, however **self.context['request'].user** and **CurrentUserDefault** don't work in my create method, so I cannot create an instance of the **LinkList** object.

The error I am getting:

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: llists_linklist.owner_id
```

Here is the **serializer**:

```
class LinkListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name="lists-detail")
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
    links = LinkSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = LinkList
        fields = ['url', 'owner', 'name', 'public', 'links']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        links = validated_data.pop('links', [])
        instance = super().create(validated_data)
        for item in links:
            instance.links.add(link=item)
        return instance
```

The **model**:

```
class LinkList(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name='lists',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    public = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    links = models.ManyToManyField(
        Link,
        related_name='linklists')

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s - %s" % (self.owner, self.name)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, the `owner` field is actually a required field and you are not passing it through the serializer as you made the `owner` field in the serializer read only.

Looks like you have two options:

**1. You do not need the owner field to be returned**

If so, just use the `HiddenField()` with `CurrentUserDefault()`:

`owner = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())`

**2. You need the owner field to be returned**

If so, just pass the user manually to the serializer's `save()` method in the view's `perform_create()` method (I assume you are using generic view):

`serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)`